# Hardware back button not working in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

On my Samsung note 5 the back button at the bottom of the phone made the phone vibrate while in the SE app but otherwise did nothing. I checked to see if it was happening in other apps and it wasn't. Otherwise the app seemed to be functioning properly. After I killed and restarted the app, the problem went away.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's like that and you must press the software back button

Comment: Did this only ever happen the one time or is it something you're able to reproduce?

Comment: It happened more than once but I don't know how to reproduce it. @Brian